# Passing UIImage array between two ViewControlllers losing values

Tags: swift, uiimageview, viewcontroller

I'm passing an array of images between 2 VCs in memory.  I don't know if this is a problem and impossible to do?  I'm getting blank images in the second view controller when it references the first's array of UIImages.

```
class ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmUploadButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CancelUploadButton: UIButton!
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let vc = CameraViewController()
        // convert to PDF
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
        for i in 0 ..< vc.images.count {
            let image = vc.images[i]
              let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image)
              pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: i)
        }
        
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        
    }
```

Edit 1:  Ok from the feedback I got and the article linked I did this:

```
func transistionToPDFView(){
        
        let vc = ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController()
        vc.images = images
        
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        

        
        view.window?.rootViewController = vc
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: Show your code from the other view controller. `vc` is a new instance. Thats why their values are empty

Comment: Please tell how do you navigate between two view controllers. At the time of navigation you will have reference of next view controller. You can simply pass the information at that time.

Comment: You should declare the images as an instance property of the `ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController` and set the image property before presenting the view controller.

Comment: @LeoDabus I did this:
 `@IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: Any) { let vc = ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController() vc.images = images transistionToPDFView()     }` But its still null

Comment: @jstocke2 You need to present the same controller that you are setting the images. `pdfViewController.images = images`

Comment: Just delete `let vc = ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController()`, `vc.images = images` and `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `CameraViewController`. That's incorrect. Every time you create new instance of `CameraViewController` it will be altogether new reference.

You should access the already available / created instance of the `CameraViewController`.

When performing segue or navigating between view controllers, you can pass the data from one view controller to another.

Let's say you have A and B view controllers, at the time navigation between A to B you can do something like this:

`let b = B() // Instantiate B view controller from storyboard with identifier`

`b.images = images // Data to pass to the next view controller`

If you want to understand it properly, you can refer to this article:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers

Comment: I tried this:  
`@IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: Any) { let vc = ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController() vc.images = images transistionToPDFView()
    }`
I thought this was basically what you were getting at but its still null?

Comment: @jstocke2 access ViewController from storyboard and use the same to present or push in the navigation

Comment: Are you presenting `ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController `?  where is that code? If you are presenting / pushing use that instance to pass the information.

Comment: In `ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController` create one variable which can hold the images array and from the controller you are presenting `ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController` you just need pass the data.

Comment: Don't create instance of `CameraViewController ` in the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: As added above I added the line about presenting the vc.  
`let vc = ViewPDFAfterSnapshotViewController()
        vc.images = images
        
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

And I got rid of the CameraViewController() instance in viewDidLoad.
Its still null though.